# If loop with OR

Tags: shell, if-statement

I have following strings in input.txt file.

```
Running
isn't running
is running
Stopped
stopped
Aborted
aborted
```

Here I would need to match everything except "Running" and "is running". So far I have done below but it seems to be printing "Running" and "is running" as well. Can some help ?

```
exec < input.txt
while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ [Aa]borted || [Ss]topped || isn*t ]]; then
        echo "$line"
    else
        echo "FINE"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -vE '\<(R|is r)unning\>' input.txt
```

The `\<` and `\>` markers are word boundaries, so you won't filter out "this running"

In shell

```bsh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
    *"Running"* | *"is running"*) echo FINE ;;
    *) echo "$line" ;;
    esac
done < input.txt
```

---

Problem in your code: this line

```
[[ $line =~ [Aa]borted || [Ss]topped || isn*t ]]
```

is **not** equivalent to this

```
[[ $line =~ [Aa]borted ]] || [[ $line =~ [Ss]topped ]] || [[ $line =~ isn*t ]]
```

it **is** equivalent to this

```
[[ $line =~ [Aa]borted ]] || [[ -n "[Ss]topped" ]] || [[ -n "isn*t" ]]
```

because the "or" operator `||` has higher precedence than the regex match operator `=~`

Since the last 2 conditions are always true, each line passes.

Note also that you're using glob patterns with a regular expression match operator, so this `[[ $line =~ isn*t ]]` will not match `isn't`, it will match `is` and `t` with zero or more `n` in between. (`ist`, `isnt`, `isnnt`, etc)

You intended to write this

```
[[ $line == [Aa]borted || $line == [Ss]topped || $line == isn*t ]]
```

which is mote concisely written with case:

```
case $line in 
    [Aa]borted | [Ss]topped | isn*t) echo "$line" ;;
    *) echo FINE ;;
esac
```

which is the inverse of my answer.

Comment: Thanks..But can you please tell what's wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use grep?

```
grep -v "unning" < input.txt
```

gives you desired lines.

Comment: I need to match the exact words